# What's the difference between skip and ignore commands in Jaseci?

Tags: jaseci

I don't get clearly where to use `skip` command and where to use `ignore` command. I checked the Jaseci Bible, but I couldn't find any details about `ignore` command. I understand that `skip` command tells a walker to halt and abandon any unfinished work on the current node and move to the next node (or complete computation if no nodes are queued up). As I understood the `ignore` command completely ignore the execution of the node? isn't it?

I'm confused already.
Please, someone explain me more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are 100% correct on the way `skip` works. `ignore` is a little bit more nuanced. In a nutshell once a node/edge or set of node/edges are "tagged" ignore, all future take commands will not be able to see that node/edge (ie walk paths through that node). You can think of using `ignore` commands as pruning a graph path.